# Concatenar dos Arrays y mostarlo en un ListView

Tags: c#, array, windows-forms

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo dos arrays cuyos valores los obtengo de dos listView. Lo que pretendo es concatenar los dos Arrays en un tercero y mostrar el resultado en un tercer listView.

Cuando digo concatenar es porque quiero que el row 1 del listView 1 se concatene con el row 1 del listview 2 y así con todos los valores de los arrays.

Ejemplo:

```
array1: a,b,c,d
array2: e,f,g,h
array3 o listView = a b c d e f g h
```

Los Arrays ya los puedo concatenar, ahora me devuelve un error al intentar guardar los datos en el ListView.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(listData.Items.Count > 0 || listCapture.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();
                ArrayList bList = new ArrayList();


                string delimiter = ";";
                for (int i = 0; i < listData.Items.Count; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < listCapture.Items.Count; j++)
                    {
                        string columns = String.Empty;
                        columns += listData.Items[i].Text + delimiter;
                        columns += listData.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text + delimiter;
                        columns += listData.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text + delimiter;
                        columns += listData.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text + delimiter;
                        columns += listData.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text + delimiter;
                        columns += listData.Items[i].SubItems[5].Text + delimiter;
                        columns += listData.Items[i].SubItems[6].Text + delimiter;

                        aList.Add(columns);
                        {
                            string col = String.Empty;
                            col += listCapture.Items[j].Text + delimiter;
                            col += listCapture.Items[j].SubItems[1].Text + delimiter;
                            col += listCapture.Items[j].SubItems[2].Text + delimiter;
                            col += listCapture.Items[j].SubItems[3].Text;
                            bList.Add(col);
                        }
                       aList.AddRange(bList); 
                    }                    

                ***//Bloque para insertar los valores al ListView*** 

                foreach (string line in aList)
                {
                    string[] split = line.Split(';');

                    if(split.Length>0)
                    {
                        
                        for(int i =0; i<split.Length;i++)
                        {
                            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(split[i]);
                            lvi.SubItems.Add(split[i]);
                            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
                            lvi = new ListViewItem();
                        }
                    }
                    lblItems.Text = listView1.Items.Count.ToString();               
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Lists null");
        }
    }
```

ListView

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano gracias por la ayuda que se me puede brindar.

DS

Answer (score 2):

Mira a ver si esto te sirve:

```
arr1.AddRange(arr2);
```

De esta forma los elementos qué hay en **arr1** y **arr2** se concatenan y se guardan en **arr1**. Para añadir el arreglo al **ListView** pon esto:

```
listView1.View = View.List;

foreach (var a in arr1)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(a.ToString());
}
```

Aquí se recorren los elementos de **arr1** y se van añadiendo uno a uno al **ListView**.

Comment: Asumo que tengo que llenar todos los elementos del array1 y array2 en el arr3, correcto?
@Japv

Comment: Creo no es viable lo que comentas, me esta dando este error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.ArrayList'
@Japv

Comment: Si quedo como comentabas 
aList.AddRange(bList);
Pero lo principal es, como meter la matriz concatenada a un listView?@Japv

Comment: Disculpa el código correcto es arr1.AddRange(arr2); de esta forma arr1 y arr2 se concatenan y se guardan en arr1

Comment: Casi lo tengo ya lleno el listView pero como implemento el Split para separar los datos y que cada uno de ellos se agregue en una columna del ListView?
foreach (string line in aList)
                    {
                        var items = new ListViewItem();
                        items.Text = line;
                        listView1.Items.Add(items);

                    }
@Japv

Comment: Pero hay que separar el arrya previamente ya que esta concatenada con ";", edite la pregunta haciendo énfasis al error que me arroja. Estoy usando este código:
foreach (string line in aList)
{string[] split = line.Split(';');
if(split.Length>0)
{
 ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(split[0]);
 for(int i =1; i<split.Length;i++)
  {
 lvi.SubItems.Add(split[i]);
 listView1.Items.Add(lvi.ToString());
 lvi = new ListViewItem();
@Japv

Comment: Hay una cosa que no estás haciendo bien, los arreglos en c# empiezan en la posición 0 y no en la 1 por lo que te debería quedar del siguiente modo            . for(int i =0; i<split.Length - 1; i++) y al Length también debes restarle 1

Comment: Hice la corrección sabes que solo me esta guardando los valores en dos columnas como la nueva imagen que subi a la pregunta y si hago uso del ToString solo me guarda esto ListViewItem:{} en una sola columna.
Entonces aun no puedo guardar la matriz concatenada en el ListView, ahora que puede estar mal?
@Japv

Comment: Este código va dentro del for            
   ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(split[0]);          y en vez de spli[0] debería ser split[i] y edita tu comentario para ver los arreglos en el código y así ubicarme mejor

Comment: Edite de nuevo la pregunta, y puse el código con las correcciones mencionadas el código corregido corre a partir de la nota "Bloque para insertar los valores al listView"
1, no esta separando los valores en cada columna del listView
2, Solo agrega los valores a dos columnas
3, array1 y array 2 contienen la misma cantidad de filas 5 cada una al concatenarla y mostrar los datos al listView1 deberia de ser 5 filas con ambos valores de la matriz concatenados.
4, En lugar de cinco valores me esta mostrando 1500 registros
@Japv

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113596/discussion-between-jdanielsolisv-and-japv).

Comment: Dime donde te encuentro